# Error with Hanami has_many associations (in 1.1.0.beta1)

Tags: hanami, hanami-model

I am using `Hanami 1.1.0.beta1` (because I need associations).

An `event` can have many `actions`:

```
class EventRepository < Hanami::Repository
  associations do
    has_many :actions
    ...
  end

class ActionRepository < Hanami::Repository
  associations do
    ...
    belongs_to :event
  end
```

When I call this `EventRepository` method:

```
  def add_action(event, data)
    assoc(:actions, event).add(data)
  end
```

I get this error:

> ```
>   KeyError:
>     key not found: :id
>   # /home/eric/.gem/ruby/2.3.4/gems/hanami-model-1.1.0.beta1/lib/hanami/model/associations/has_many.rb:195:in `fetch'
>   # /home/eric/.gem/ruby/2.3.4/gems/hanami-model-1.1.0.beta1/lib/hanami/model/associations/has_many.rb:195:in `_build_scope'
>   # /home/eric/.gem/ruby/2.3.4/gems/hanami-model-1.1.0.beta1/lib/hanami/model/associations/has_many.rb:47:in `initialize'
>   # /home/eric/.gem/ruby/2.3.4/gems/hanami-model-1.1.0.beta1/lib/hanami/model/association.rb:20:in `new'
>   # /home/eric/.gem/ruby/2.3.4/gems/hanami-model-1.1.0.beta1/lib/hanami/model/association.rb:20:in `build'
>   # /home/eric/.gem/ruby/2.3.4/gems/hanami-model-1.1.0.beta1/lib/hanami/repository.rb:472:in `assoc'
>   ...
> ```

I looked in has_many.rb.  In `initialize` I see that `subject` is an `Event` object and it has an `id`:
`HasMany::initialize - subject: #<Event:0x00558f3c198ce8 @id=705,
@attributes={:title=>"test_title"}>`

but in `_build_scope` `subject` has changed to be just the `attributes` hash, hence the `key not found: :id` error.

> HasMany::_build_scope - subject: {:title=>"test_title"}

which is weird because I don't see any place where `subject` is changed between `initialize` and `_build_scope`...

So is this a bug is 1.1.0.beta1, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you please share a snippet of code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I found a fix, or a workaround at least.  I added `  def to_hash
    if id
      super.merge(id: id)
    else
      super
    end
  end` in my `class Event < Hanami::Entity` and that fixed the crash.

Comment: Would you mind to report this problem? Thanks! https://github.com/hanami/model/issues/new

Comment: I reported this problem, and also another similar one.

Comment: Can you please report the similar one as well? Thank you very much!

Comment: I reported both problems in one issue: https://github.com/hanami/model/issues/447

Comment: Thanks, let's move the discussion over there. I replied to the problems.